# Enable write permission for directory in Linux

Tags: linux, file-permissions

I keep trying to move files from a directory on Linux- but I keep getting permission errors.

Initially I was told

```
sudo chmod -R r+w /directory/*
```

But this only applies it to the directory folder (and not the files inside)

Answer (score 0):

Trick is- you need to "select all" to apply the file permissions to:

```
sudo chmod -R a+rwx,go-w /directory/
```

And that's it

Comment: Did you just answer your own question

Answer (score 0):

Or you could do `sudo chmod 777 /dir/`
and that's just a simple way to do the answer stated above.

Comment: Ok yep- simpler way to do it. Thanks

Comment: Actually that did not work- only method that seems to work for me is "sudo chmod -R a+rwx,go-w /directory/"